# One-sided vs two-sided hypothesis: Does the written hypothesis need to match the statistical test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, reporting

The analysis I am doing is two-sided. I was told that the written hypothesis should match the analysis, but this doesn't make sense to me.

I had written something like: "It is hypothesized that applying treatment A will increase response times". This is what I see hypotheses written as in my field.

However, it would seem strange to change it to "It is hypothesized that applying treatment A will have an effect on response times".

If it helps, my analysis is ANOVA. I am interested in how the treatment affects response times - whether they increase or decrease and by how much. It is likely that treatment A will increase them, which is why I hypothesized that.

Comment: Say the application of treatment is associated with a reduction in response times. Is that a finding that would interest you? Would you be surprised by that finding, or perhaps you wouldn’t care/be interested?

Comment: Yes, it would definitely be of interest, although surprising.

Comment: If you are interested in increase then you have to run one sided hypothesis test